# Generate a triangle of stars using mySQL recursive CTE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to generate a triangle of stars in MYSQL that looks like this:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I'm using the following code to do in MYSQL

```
with recursive print_star(n) as (
    select '*'
    UNION ALL
    select concat(n,'*')
    from print_star
    where length(n)<5
)
select * from print_star order by length(n) desc
```

I get the error "Data too long for column 'n' at row 1". Can anybody help me find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess MySQL is finicky about types.  Try this:

```
with recursive print_star(n) as (
    select cast('*' as char(255)) n
    union all
    select concat(n, '*')
    from print_star
    where length(n) < 5
)
select *
from print_star
order by length(n) desc
```

Comment: Any idea what type '*' was before we cast it to a char(255)?

Comment: @NipunParasrampuria . . . I am guessing `char(1)`.  SQL Server has the same issue, of paying attention to the length of strings in recursive CTEs.  You'd think that the MySQL folks would want to avoid a known problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the additional context! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: @NipunParasrampuria: it is a varchar(1).  `create table abcd as select '*'; desc abcd;`